# Updating the Map objects in java

Tags: java

Trying to use a Map variable with key as id and value as the custom object in a java based system.

```
 Map<long, CustomBean> customBeanMap = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
```

Couple of questions:

1. During update of the object that is already in the cache, what is the best practice:

   - get the value based on the key
   - update the local value
   - update the value in the Map cache // is this instruction needed??
2. Since the system is highly concurrent and deployed in multiple cores and multiple concurrent threads will be active, should the modifier for the customBeanMap must have volatile modifier?

Answer (score 1):

Your question is ill written but I'll try to answer it still.

1. Updating the value for a specific key should be done using a put (map.put(, ). This is even more important to do in a highly concurrent environment where reading a value then updating it can lead to unexpected results.
2. If you must read the previous value in order to determine the next value, I suggest using a lock mechanism to ensure that all actions on the map are done separately (unless you have verified that this is not necessary for your application)
3. I am less experienced with the use of volatile so I can't help you there
4. Your value is an object (the actual object that is also in the map) so updating it will also update the map, naturally.

Good luck,
Roy.

Comment: Volatile modifier makes the other threads aware when you change the assigned value of the variable. If you will create the map only once, then there is no need for the modifier, since all the threads will have the same reference. If in some stage you use another map to replace the current one, you will need the keyword volatile to avoid having the other threads referencing and modifying the old map.